# Backtrader - trades not lining up on .plot

Tags: python, backtrader

I am trying to learn backtrader, but when using my own data (1 min. charts), I am having this issue, where the trades are not lining up with the graph.
[image: Graop]

Don't mind the many trades, there is not set a proper strategy at the moment as I am just testing out and trying to learn backtrader.
I have looked around and read the reply's for other people who were having same issue.
What fixed it for them in most cases was to add stdstats=False and a BuySell observer.

```py
cerebro = bt.Cerebro(stdstats=False)
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.BuySell)
```

I have also declared that my timeframe is minutes:

```py
data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(
        dataname='BTCUSD2.csv',
        timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes,
        fromdate=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 17),
        reverse=False)
```

I simply can't figure out what else might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice other reports of this kind o problem here:

- https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2077/plot-buysell-observer-with-tick-data
- https://community.backtrader.com/topic/1574/problem-with-plotting-buy-sell-arrows
- https://community.backtrader.com/topic/8/change-buysell-to-trade-arrows-in-charts-213
- https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2077/plot-buysell-observer-with-tick-data

basically you need to change this line, and add `barplot` and `bardist` according [documentation](https://www.backtrader.com/docu/observers-reference/#buysell)

```
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.BuySell, barplot=True, bardist=0.0025)
```

the value above 0.0025 is just an example.